# Is it possible send data in realtime in iPhone app to an php aplication?

Tags: php, iphone

I want to make an iPhone app that sends some data to a PHP web site, I know it can be done with a web service, but how? Can be done in realtime? If I got several iPhones how can I make my app?

Comment: this is a wide question. Be more specific than that. You can use GET queries, for one thing. For realtime, query at regular intervals. I am guessing ur starting with iOS so won't go into sockets

Comment: what do sockets do in this case?

Comment: maintain a persistent connection with the server. You would need node.js, or something similar. http://websocket.org/

What are you doing exactly?

Comment: I just want to send a message -data to a php app and the return a confirmation message to the app iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSString *content = @"message=Message&user=21";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/form.php"]];//The address of the website page
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; //Method GET/POST. POST is recommended
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];


// generates an autoreleased NSURLConnection
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

From : [How to write data to the web server from iphone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334055/how-to-write-data-to-the-web-server-from-iphone-application)

Comment: thanks so if I want to send several messages at the same time?

Comment: you can develop your script to accept multiple messages http://davidwalsh.name/checkbox-form-input-arrays or you can send multiple requests a syncronously

Comment: I do, ofcourse. i wouldn't be posting things here otherwise

Comment: for which part? iOS or PHP? i mean sending the data or receiving it at server side?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7992/discussion-between-somesh-mukherjee-and-georgebecj)

Answer (score 1):

You can use json formatted data to be send to the php application as an webservice call. Php have the option to get the data from the json format.Also php application can return the response in json format which can be processed by the iphone.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your data as querystring with your link

e.g. www.yoursite.com/option/update?id=

Send as HttpRequest

Comment: I see in other questions thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to accomplish this in iOS is through RESTful services. Many website expose their data through GET queries. Any results are returned in a machine readable format such as JSON or XML (rather than as a standard HTML).

Twitter, for instance, has a [RESTful API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api).

As an example try http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue%20angels&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed

This returns a search for tweets with the phrase "blue angels."

Assuming you want to access your own website through PHP, you'll need to create your own API (webpages that return results in a RESTful format).

[Here](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/consuming-a-restful-service-bit-ly-in-an-iphone-application/) is one blog tutorial that describes the process of consuming a RESTful service through iOS.

Comment: thanks for answer I have worked with the twitter API